# Cannot open material datapicker using ngAfterViewInit by element id

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to open material DatePicker when component loaded using element id (#).
When I try use ngAfterViewInit it always return `'cannot use 'open' to undefined'`.
It works when I click calendar icon or even add click property to a button  with `open()` function.

I created simple stackblitz page here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dkbsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html when you can check what I want to acheive.

`picker` ID is defined as a material element that should open modal with calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the wrong type to picker,it should be `MatDatepicker` not a `ElementRef`

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('picker',{static:false}) picker: MatDatepicker;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.picker.open();
  }
}
```